# Minimum distance between click targets

Tags: usability, website-design, fittslaw

What is the minimum distance between click targets on web for an optimal UX?

I have read this article: [An Interactive Visualisation of Fitts's Law](http://simonwallner.at/ext/fitts/)

[image: the screenshot from the article]

Here is a menu with items I'm trying to position in the best way:

[image]

According to the Fitts's Law **the smaller distance is the better**. So if I make the distance smaller it will be less difficult to hit it, but **with small distance between two items I can miss and click accidentally the other one.**

So applying Fitts's Law in this case could make users **miss the targets**.

Is the any formula that takes into accounting, let's say, MD variable (minimum distance to not click accidentally other closely existing target)?

Comment: I think you're making an assumption that Fitts's law isn't appropriate here. You say '*with small distance between two items I can miss and click accidentally the other one*' - why do you say this?

I believe Fitts's law still applies here. It's not just distance, but speed at which the user is able to move from one to another. By virtue of how close they are to eachother the user will not be moving their cursor at speed, so the chances of missing / overshooting are low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distance between targets can be next to zero. Like in the menu you have. What you are missing here is the size of the target. It is easier to miss the target if it is too small. As from the image of Fitts's law you posted:

> From this formula we can see that the task gets harder, the **farther away** the target is and the **smaller** it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to consider **the medium of interaction here - cursor vs finger**.

The links arranged here (UX.SE desktop version) are perfect to interact with without any accidental clicks, because **cursor provides a lot better precision**.

[image]

---

But, the same will not work well on mobile app, because the **medium of interaction is finger which requires enough space between the links to avoid accidental taps**:

[image]