# Gaps between active areas of menu items

Tags: navigation, menu, hyperlinks, placement

What is a better solution to make gaps between active areas of menu items or place them close to each other? I'm asking just about active areas of links not about visual styles.

[image]
For example, maybe gaps help to aim on touch devices. Is it not good when cursor switches between pointer and normal when it hovers on menu?

Live demo
https://codepen.io/rmnturov/full/KJqWjq

Comment: Also related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/106085/minimum-distance-between-click-targets/